# Is it possible to get the physical shape of a touch contact (a bitmap) in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, touch

I want to be able to determine the size AND rotation of touch contacts for a finger painting app. Right now laying down a long finger diagonally gives me a giant square, which is not what I want at all, I want a long rectangle at an angle.

I figured this would be provided by the system, but even the Surface Pro 4 hardware doesn't have this. But I could extract the info if I had a bitmap of the contact area.

So far googling `WM_INPUT` related things hasn't helped. Is this even possible?

Edit: a way to get `POINTER_TOUCH_INFO::orientation` is what I'm looking for, to be precise. My touch screen doesn't put any value into this field.

Edit 2: There's some useful research on this (http://hci.cs.umanitoba.ca/assets/publication_files/2009-UIST-wang-DirectTouchSurface.pdf), all I need now is access to the contact shape.

Edit 3: I got an answer from @msdev, they also suggest motion tracking. The only thing lacking now is continuous tracking, and I guess there's no way to reliably solve that without a contact bitmap. Maybe teaching a neural net could work.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 8 there are new messages:
 - WM_POINTERUP
 - WM_POINTERDOWN
 - WM_POINTERUPDATE